# Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime not invariant under metric perturbation gauge transformations

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

[Gauge transformation in general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302839/)

This post states that

$$h_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu \tag{1}$$

Is a gauge transformation for a spin-2 field.
It seems to me that one can verify this by checking that, for linearised gravity which is only first order in the metric perturbation and its derivatives:

$$R_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow  R_{\mu\nu} \tag{2}$$

I.e. the linearised ricci tensor, and thereby the Einstein Field Equations in vacuum, are gauge invariant under transformation (1). Indeed this is the case.

Then if we couple the gravitational field to the electromagnetic field we get, among others, Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime:

$$\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = 0 \tag{3}$$

Which is invariant under the transformation:

$$ A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \partial_\mu \Lambda \tag{4}$$

Because $F^{\mu\nu}$ is.

Now it seems to me that equation (3) should be gauge invariant under some (perhaps simultaneous) gauge transformations (1) and (4) as is the case with the respective gauge transformations for uncoupled spin-1/2 and spin-1 fields when ones does couple them.

Now by using the linearised Christoffel symbols:

$$\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\eta^{\alpha\lambda}(h_{\lambda\mu,\nu} + h_{\lambda\nu,\mu}-h_{\mu\nu,\lambda})$$

One can show that under the transformation (1):

$$ \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha \rightarrow \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha + \partial_{\mu\nu}\xi^\alpha \tag{5}$$

And using the definition of the covariant derivative:

$$ \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma_{\mu\alpha}^\nu F^{\mu\alpha} + \Gamma_{\mu\alpha}^\mu F^{\alpha\nu} \tag{6}$$

We find that:

$$ \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} + \partial_{\mu\alpha}\xi^\nu F^{\mu\alpha} - \partial_{\mu\alpha}\xi^\mu F^{\nu\alpha} \tag{7}$$

These two extra invariance-breaking terms are themselves gauge invariant under (4) so (4) cannot help us eliminate these terms. So have we learnt that when spin-2 field couple to spin 1 fields we can only use (1) under the constraint:

$$\partial_{\mu\alpha}\xi^\nu F^{\mu\alpha} = \partial_{\mu\alpha}\xi^\mu F^{\nu\alpha} \tag{8}$$

Because if so, it seems very unlikely to me that we can ever use the transverse-traceless gauge for gravitational waves when describing a spacetime that interacts with an arbitrary electromagnetic field on it...

Comment: Given that gauge transformations in GR are changes of coordinates and that Maxwell's equations are tensorial, I think there might be a miscalculation in there somewhere. Perhaps the electromagnetic field changes under a change of gravitational gauge, just like Dirac fields change under a change of electromagnetic gauge

Comment: Hint: The (2,0) contravariant tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ depends on the metric, and hence transforms under GR gauge transformations (1).